# Set axes label in GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, axes

I want to have displayed the axes labels on my plot before I click the start button that only then shows all the axes labels and contents.

I thought i could add this information on

`function plot_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)` but this doesn't exist.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What? Can you show an example or some code? Also which labels are you talking about? `xlabel` and `ylabel`?

Comment: yes! So when I run the gui the plot is all plane with no labels on it. When i start my calculation by hitting the start button only then the x and ylabels are being added. I added the plot specs. under the pushbutton callback

Comment: Please see: [mcve]

Comment: @jdoubleu Ok so add the labels in the GUI's init function.